# Is it possible to force a transitive dependency in gradle to be runtime only?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I recently updated a large project to use java.time instead of joda.time. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to remove joda.time completely from the classpath because some thirdparty dependencies depend on it. Since many classes in joda.time and java.time have the same or similar names, I wanted to avoid other members of the team accidentally importing and using joda.time in new code when their IDE tries to be helpful and adds the import statement for them. To that end, I wanted to update the build.grade file to make the joda.time dependency runtime only.

I ended up adding a `runtimeOnly('joda-time:joda-time:2.10.8')` line to my dependencies configuration and then for each dependency that pulled in joda I added an `exclude module: 'joda-time'`. This works but requires that the same exclude be added every time anyone adds a new dependency that uses joda (which is likely to be forgotten) and was extra annoying when joda wasn't a direct dependency (if my project needs A which depends on B which depends on joda I had to configure A with an exclude of B and include B myself with an exclude of joda). I'd rather have something at a higher level, like how adding exclude statements to `configurations.all` excludes a dependency from everything.

There are obviously other solutions to this involving IDE configuration changes, linting rules, developer training, etc; but I would like to know if there's a straightforward way to tell gradle to convert a transitive dependency from being on the compile and runtime classpaths to being runtime only.